# Hang On Serial.Close(), Possible threading Issue?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, serial-port

The software im currently working on sometimes hangs when I close the serial port. Its intermittent and works fine 90% of the time but I clearly have an issue. When I ctl+Alt+Break it shows that its waiting on serial.Close().

I have lots a data coming in and out on the serial port which is being invoked to a number of forms so is this a threading issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this may be the case. [See this post](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=202137). [See also here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/68d3e00b-aae7-40db-afba-8a4ee7b210e2/), which suggests that using BeginInvoke rather than Invoke may solve your problem.

Also, if you're using a USB serial adapator, you could have a driver problem. Some of those drivers are poorly written and can cause a whole host of problems.

Comment: BeginInvoke on all of my module GUI code was going to be too scary so i used the other tip from the link you posted.
I spawn another thread which closes the port!